# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException setSpan (2 ... 2) ends beyond length 0 -React Native

Tags: react-native

This is from a firebase log which i am receiving from the production app for Android only:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
setSpan (2 ... 2) ends beyond length 0 
Environment Details:
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.0",
```

It is not reproducible at the debug environment but some users are facing a crash due to this issue in production. Any solution/workaround for this issue?